# Why would my parameterized query not use indexes correctly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sap-ase, sql-execution-plan

This is in SQL Server 2014, but I'm seeing the same behavior in 2008, 2012, and 2016, as well as Sybase ASE 15.7.

I have a simple query that looks like this:

```
SELECT myField
FROM myTable
WHERE someIndexedField = @myParam
```

If I run this query from SSMS (replacing @myParam with 'myValue'), the query runs in under a second, because someIndexedField is indexed, and lookups should be very fast.
However, if I create the same query as a parameterized query string in a C# program, the query takes 20 to 30 seconds. Analysis by the DBAs shows that the query plan is NOT using the index on the someIndexedField column, but it is instead doing a table scan.

Even stranger, if I do the exact same parameterized query, but instead change it slightly to this:

```
DECLARE @_myParam char(13)
SET @_myParam = @myParam

SELECT myField
FROM myTable
WHERE someIndexedField = @_myParam
```

...this version suddenly uses the index again, and performance is back up to sub-second response times. I see this same behavior in queries of various complexity, but not 100% consistently for different queries - sometimes the server DOES decide to use an index. It IS, however, consistent for any given query. I never know which queries will be affected before trying them, but if a given query has this problem, it ALWAYS has the problem. Also, a query that does not have the problem doesn't ever seem to develop it later.

Another odd thing I have noticed is that sometimes, changing the total length of the query will actually make a difference in how this behavior shows up. I had one example where adding extra carriage returns into the query (essentially double-spacing it) actually caused the server to suddenly start using indexes as expected. Literally NO CODE was changed. I was unable to pin down an exact length at which this happened, however. Also, this particular "solution" only seemed to work on Sybase ASE - I was unable to reproduce that one on SQL Server.

(Incidentally, I can also use a hint to push the server to use the appropriate index, and this also fixes the problem. However, index hints are generally not a good idea if you can avoid them, and it seems that the server should be perfectly capable of picking an index on its own, especially with such a simple query.)

What's going on here? Why is the first version running as though there were no indexes on the table? And why does simply putting the parameter into a locally defined variable suddenly cause indexes to be used?

Comment: What's the actual field type in the table?

Comment: What is the type and length of the parameter in your C# code?

Comment: @alroc I have used the example here of a char(12) database field, with the C# parameter using the type DBType.String, but I have reproduced the issue with int/DBType.Int32, datetime/DBType.DateTime, smallint/DBType.Int16, and bigint/DBType.Int64.

Comment: @ps2goat In this case, the field is char(12), but as I mention in my comment to alroc above, I can reproduce the issue with many different parameter and column types.

Comment: What is the definition of the variable in the first query, which is running fine

Comment: how are you calling it in C# ?

Comment: Execution plans are cached with a combination key: (1) being the hash of the SQL statement (sans substituted parameter values); (2) being the current @@OPTIONS value. It's not surprising that changing the code slightly changes the performance - it would do that even when adding or removing white space. It's also not surprising that your query can perform differently from C# compared with SSMS - they use different SET options. Your DBAs should have a read through [Execution Plan Basics](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/)

Comment: I was asking about the field type because sometimes a field type mismatch can cause SQL Server to not use indexes or to make it convert values during the search (meaning a full table scan). See example [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4380/sql-server-performance-issues-when-using-mismatched-data-types/)